# Timemapper.js - trying to get map bounds

Tags: leaflet

I've got an application using Timemapper.js (http://timemapper.okfnlabs.org/), which uses Leaflet maps set up through Recline.js.  I want to get the leaflet map's bounds and when trying to use this.map.getBounds() come up with an '... is not a function' error.

Here is the map code from view.js.

```
_setupMap: function() {
 this.map = new recline.View.Map({
  model: this.model
});
this.$el.find('.map').append(this.map.el);

// customize with icon column
this.map.infobox = function(record) {
  if (record.icon !== undefined) {
    return '<img src="' + record.get('icon') + '" width="100px"> ' + record.get('title');
  }
  return record.get('title');
};

this.map.geoJsonLayerOptions.pointToLayer = function(feature, latlng) {
  var record = this.model.records.get(feature.properties.cid);
  var recordAttr = record.toJSON();
  var maxSize = 400;
  var radius = parseInt(Math.sqrt(maxSize * recordAttr.relativeSize));
  if (radius) {
    var marker = new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {
      radius: radius,
      fillcolor: '#fe9131',
      color: '#fe9131',
      opacity: recordAttr.opacity,
      fillOpacity: recordAttr.opacity * 0.9
    });
  } else {
    var marker = new L.Marker(latlng, {
      opacity: recordAttr.opacity
    });
  }
  var label = recordAttr.title + '<br />Date: ' + recordAttr.start;
  if (recordAttr.size) {
    label += '<br />Size: ' + recordAttr.size;
  }
  marker.bindLabel(label);

  // customize with icon column
  if (recordAttr.icon !== undefined) {
    var eventIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: recordAttr.icon,
        iconSize:     [100, 20], // size of the icon
        iconAnchor:   [22, 94], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
        shadowAnchor: [4, 62],  // the same for the shadow
        popupAnchor:  [-3, -76] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
    });
    marker.setIcon(eventIcon);
  }

  // this is for cluster case
  // this.markers.addLayer(marker);

  // When a marker is clicked, update the fragment id, which will in turn update the timeline
  marker.on("click", function (e) {
    var i = _.indexOf(record.collection.models, record);
    window.location.hash = "#" + i.toString();
  });

  // Stored so that we can get from record to marker in hashchange callback
  record.marker = marker;

  return marker;
};
this.map.render();
```

}
});